# Is there a better alternative for "remainderless"?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, mathematics

I want to express in one word whether a number has a remainder or not.

as an example:

- `3.5 is not remainderless`
- `3 is remainderless`

It might seem that something like `"3 is whole"` or `"3 is an integer"` fits better but it is important that remainders, floating points or decimals are directly adressed.

---

Why I require this: I have a scenario where I want to express in a C++ function whether

[image: log_a b]

yields an integer or a decimal. This is constant compile time arithmetic which I have implemented to solely work with integers - so actually asking if an result *"is an integer"* is superfluous as every result is always an integer.

The intent for this function is to stand out by actually talking about floating points. Since this is impossible to execute it behaves on a more hypothetical level as in saying: *"would the result `log(a, b)`, hypothetically, have a remainder"*.

As for a function that stands out in an "integer saturated environment" I find it to be a necessity to include unorthodox, contrastive wording - like `remainderless`.

---

Which made me wonder is there is a better, mathematical adequate synonym for `remainderless` while still talking about decimals.

Comment: The mathematical term for any number not an integer is 'non-integral', better used as a noun [modifier] 'non-integer'. How you then convert the initial number to another (integer) number (eg 3.14159 becomes 3142) is immaterial; 3.14159 remains a non-integer. // One _could_ call non-integers 'numbers having a non-zero decimal part', but why bother?

Comment: You're not looking for 'mantissa' are you? It's a special name for 'the decimal part of a number but only when that number is the evaluated logarithm, to a specified base, of an original number'.  Eg, with log123 = 2.08990 (truncated), the mantissa is 0.0899 (4dp). It is a term rarely used for numbers in general (ie when not 'using logs'; the term was useful when logs were commonly used for numerical calculations in say schools.

Comment: So basically you're looking for a word meaning *exponential in base* (probably not understood without context). Basically, you're asking what is to logarithm what cube is to the cube root?

Comment: @JJJ I yes you are correct. So when talking exponentiation, `exponentiation_of_a_fits_b` seems like a decent workaround. The Problem is that it doesn't adress `log` and that could be problematic.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I would have to go for `mantissaless` then, which is correct but seems worse than `remainderless`.

Comment: Can't you just use *(non-)integral* on the `log`? If you use it a lot you can even say `x=log` or `f(a,b)=log` and then refer to that. If you use it a whole lot more you can even consider an indicator function (take 1 when log is integer and 0 otherwise). It doesn't seem like something to be solved through the English language.

Comment: @JJJ the implementation works perfectly already, the problem I have is spelling it expressively. As an example: `log_a_b_remainderless(5, 25)` yields `true` as `log(5, 25)` is an integer (`2`). To adress the problem regarding exponentiantion let's assume I call it `exponentiation_of_a_fits_b` but it still operates on `log`: `exponentiation_of_a_fits_b(0,  1)` should yield `true` but it won't do that because `log(0, 1)` is undefined. Bad stuff. I could hard-code that, but at that point it's a mess and far from elegant.

Comment: @StackDanny so you're just asking about the name in your program? If that's the case, and it's not about a report or paper that has to be understood by those not working with your system (e.g. for reproducibility) then I don't think it's worth overthinking.

Comment: @JJJ I agree that it's a bit overthinking. However, the code is part of a large library implementation which could be difficult to maintain in the future if not designed consistent and with care.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notion of a remainder is associated with division -- it's what remains after subtracting the divisor as many times as possible.  Note that the remainder is *not* the fraction part of the result.  The remainder in 25/10 is 5, and the remainder in 20/8 is 4, even though those operations produce the same result.

There is no notion of a "remainder" associated with the logarithm.

I think you want to say that when *b* is a power of *a*, then your function produces an **exact** result.

Comment: Absolutely right, I'd got sucked into thinking of 'remainder' as being the same as 'non-integer part' which, of course, it isn't. On reflection I think that the OP's best naming option is **log_a_b_is_integer(a,b)**. That says it all and implies a boolean return, the base a log of b is either an integer, has a non-integer part or is undefined. If it's undefined it isn't an integer any more than the result of 1/0 is an integer.

Comment: This is correct. My implementation will probably be that `log(a, b)` returns a proxy state so I can write: `can_be_representable_as_integer(log(a, b));` or `yields_exact_integer_value(log(a, b));`. Since this is compile time evaluation I do not have to worry about performance as all of this gets inlined and disappears before runtime. Thanks to you Matt. And @BoldBen for correctly identifying the matter and expanding upon it.

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you're looking for is a variable or function called something like *IsRemainderless*, which would be true when there is no remainder.  Well, that's certainly a mouthful.  But isn't this the exact opposite of "HasRemainder"?

So, this is my proposal:

**HasRemainder**

It is up to you to self-document the program so that the reader and the maintainer understand how you've set this up.

If this is unacceptable for some reason, then you could go with

**NoRemainder**

which is a more succinct version of

*HasNoRemainder*

Answer (score -2):

Programmers and computer scientists call the action of coercing a floating-point or double to an integer **truncation**. The verb is **to truncate**.

> trunc
>
> Truncate value
>
> Rounds x toward zero, returning the nearest integral value that is not larger in magnitude than x.
>
> [C++ reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/trunc/)

Perhaps your C++ function could be a Boolean called *isTruncated*.

EDIT: Mathematics
Mathematicians call the function that returns the largest integer less than or equal to a number with or without decimals **floor**.

> In mathematics and computer science, the floor function is the function that takes as input a real number x and gives as output the greatest integer less than or equal to x...
>
> [Wikipedia: Floor and ceiling functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions)

The word *floored* means *overwhelmed* in most contexts. However, in your computer programming context, you might consider *floored* (as an alternative to *remainderless* or *mantiassalessness*).

Comment: +1 from me, I didn't consider that and it fits the IT jargon.

Comment: Thank you for the +1. While I'm scratching my head over the downvote, I'm editing to add a mathematical context.

Comment: @rajah9 I didn't do the downvote but I don't believe that **truncate** expresses what StackDenny is thinking of at all. In a comment StackDenny gives the example log_a_b_remainderless(5,25) returns TRUE since the base 5 log of 25 is 2. This is true because it returns an integer. However log_a_b_remainderless(4,25) would return FALSE since 25 is not a power of 4. If you **truncated** log_a_b(4,25) you would get 2 but only log_a_b(4,16)  would return 2 as an integer. I don't believe that **truncate** works at all.